# how to poulate the dropdownlist from jquery ajax success callback

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm new to jQuery and Javascript. I have the below data from jquery ajax sucess callback.

```
["Man","KFC","fsdfds","ETA","Star","SCity ","TESTGB"]
```

Now, I want to populate this data on success callback.

```
success: function(data) {
                // Call this function on success                
                alert(data);    
               var builder_arr=data.split(',');               
              for (var i=0;i<builder_arr.length;++i)  
              {
                 builder_arr[i]+':'+builder_arr[i];
              }     

        }
```

I don't know how to populate it inside the select
How can I do this?

Comment: That's not JSON, it's just an array...if that's exactly how it is returned then your code fails because it treats it like a `string`.

Comment: @abc123 What should I do for that now?

Comment: added answer...let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 0):

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/4U4zE/)

**HTML**

```
<select id="mydropdown">
</select>
```

**JS**

```
function onSuccess(data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $('#mydropdown').append($('<option/>', { 
            value: value,
            text : value 
        }));
    }); 
}

var data = ["Man","KFC","fsdfds","ETA","Star","SCity ","TESTGB"];
onSuccess(data);
```

***Note:*** This is just a best guess given the above.